# How to stop recursion?

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion

The code below is `to find the path in a tree that adds up to a given sum`... what I do here is `enqueue` all nodes' values into a array `path` and print it if the conditions satisfies recursively....

```
void checkSum(NODE* root, int path[], int len, int sum){

     if(root == NULL) return;

     path[len] = root->data;
     len++;

     if(sum - root->data == 0){ 
            sum -= root->data;
            cout<<"\nSum equals..."; 
            printPaths(path, len); 
     }
     else if(sum - root->data > 0){
          sum -= root->data;
          checkSum(root->left, path, len, sum);    
          checkSum(root->right, path, len, sum);
     }else { return; }
}
```

What I wanna know is that is there any other way that I can print the path(atleast one) without using any data structures ???

Something lik this....

```
void checkSum_second(NODE* root, int sum){

     if(root == NULL) return;

     if(sum - root->data == 0) {  
          //do something
     }     
     else if(sum - root->data > 0){
          sum -= root->data;                 
     }else return;


     checkSum_second(root->left, sum);
     checkSum_second(root->right, sum);     
     cout<<"\nvalue..."<<root->data;
}
```

consider a tree like

```
           1
       2       3
    4    5   6   7
```

if `sum = 7` the `checkSum_second(root->left, sum);` is executed thrice i.e, till node 4, and here whether can we stop everything and just print the stack (i.e empty it)....

Answer (score 6):

To terminate recursion early, you need to pass some sort of a signal up the invocation chain. In your case, you can change the return type to `bool`, and return `true` to indicate that the search has terminated, and no further processing is needed:

```
bool checkSum(NODE* root, int path[], int len, int sum) {
     if(root == NULL) return false;
     path[len] = root->data;
     len++;
     if (sum - root->data == 0){ 
          sum -= root->data;
          cout<<"\nSum equals..."; 
          printPaths(path, len);
          return true;
     } else if (sum - root->data > 0) {
          sum -= root->data;
          if (checkSum(root->left, path, len, sum)) {
              return true;
          }
          if (checkSum(root->right, path, len, sum)) {
              return true;
          }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Note that in the above code the recursive invocations go on only while the prior invocations continue returning `false`. The first `true` returned from an invocation is sent up the invocation chain, causing the entire call chain to terminate.

Comment: One could also use `longjmp` (not recommended for C++ in the light of likely usage of RAII) or use exception mechanism to jump back up the stack.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Right, `longjmp` should not be used precisely for the RAII reasons. Exceptions, on the other hand, should not be used unless the call chain terminates in response to an exceptional situation (e.g. found a null in an unexpected place, or something equally exceptional).

Comment: Hopefully, `longjmp` will soon use Itanium ABI and unwind the stack (i.e. like NPTL's thread cancellation on Linux).

Comment: I believe OP wants to get rid of `int path[]` and just print the path as he goes - from the question - `"is there any other way that I can print the path (at least one) without using any data structures?"`. Not sure whether that or the title (or both) is the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save the path , after you have reach your number (7), move up the graph and print each nod on the way .

**Edit**: this is the code on how to do that
Note that this will:

1. Print the path from the bottom up
2. Print all the possible paths

This is the code

```
void checkSum_second(NODE* originalRoot, NODE* root, int sum){

 if(root == NULL) return;

 if(sum - root->data == 0) { 
      //do something 
      NODE* tmp = root;
      while (tmp != originalRoot) {
           print(tmp->data);
           tmp = tmp->parent;
      }
 }     
 else if(sum - root->data > 0){
      sum -= root->data;                 
 }else return;


 checkSum_second(originalRoot,root->left, sum);
 checkSum_second(originalRoot,root->right, sum);     
 cout<<"\nvalue..."<<root->data;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should print it upside-down, but I don't think there's another way if you don't want data structures.

It returns `true` when a path has been found.

```
void checkSum_second(NODE* root, int sum){
     if(root == NULL) return false;

     if(sum - root->data == 0)
     {
          cout<<"\nvalue..."<<root->data;
          return true;
     }
     else if(sum - root->data > 0)
          sum -= root->data;
     else return false;

     // if first is true, second won't get evaluated (it's the way || works)
     // if we found a path, print the current node and return true
     if (checkSum_second(root->left, sum) ||
         checkSum_second(root->right, sum))
     {
       cout<<"\nvalue..."<<root->data;
       return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```